# How can I find out if photoanalysisd and photolibraryd are making any progress?

Tags: high-sierra, mojave, photos.app

I'm using two macs, a desktop (brand new 6-core iMac 2019 running Mojave) and a laptop (2-core MBP 2013 running High Sierra). Both have (recently?) started to lose 50% of a couple of cores on `photoanalysisd` and `photolibraryd`.

Afaik, this is face recognition calculations on my Photo Library (31GB) which exists on both machines.

The laptop has now spent 100 core hours on it. For a while, I thought the iMac had finished, but it turns out it is also still doing it when I am logged in.

I see a lot of this in Console.app:

```
default 10:45:25.168363 +0200   photoanalysisd  Coordinator: asking worker: 0x7fd0810b02c0 to start job: <private>...
error   10:45:25.464623 +0200   photoanalysisd  <private>
default 10:45:25.468766 +0200   photoanalysisd  Coordinator: Job finished: <PHAFaceClusteringJob: 0x7fd0866c4cc0>
```

Is there a way to find out if this is making any progress at all?